# Windows Server 2008 Enterprise version issue

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am always confused about 3 terms about Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, sometimes people call Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Core version, sometimes people call Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Full version and sometimes people just say Windows Server 2008 Enterprise version. Are they the same thing? Any differences?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of every Windows Server 2008 operating system: the Core and Full editions.

Wikipedia has a reasonable article that explains [Server Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008#Server_Core):

> Windows Server 2008 includes a
>   variation of installation called a
>   Server Core. Server Core is a
>   significantly scaled-back installation
>   where no Windows Explorer shell is
>   installed. All configuration and
>   maintenance is done entirely through
>   command line interface windows, or by
>   connecting to the machine remotely
>   using Microsoft Management Console.
>   However, Notepad and some control
>   panel applets, such as Regional
>   Settings, are available.

The main purpose for Server Core is to limit security risk on servers by limiting what can be installed and executed.  Fundamentally they are the same, with the same hardware requirements and limitations, just a different target usage - most organisations will actually want the Full edition most of the time.

Comment: @Froosh, 1. could I understand that Full version is superset of Core version? 2. How to check whether I installed Core or Full version Windows Server 2008?

Comment: How Core edition will be able to "limit security risk on servers"? And How to check whether I installed Core or Full version Windows Server 2008?

Comment: The Server Core version *only* runs a command prompt when you log in, nothing else.  If you get the normal Explorer view (like every other Windows), then you have the full edition.